# How to create runnable jar with dependencies in extra folder on mutimodule project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have a common library that is shared among different project. As the library is constantly extended (at least for now), it should just be picked up from eclipse workspace during build.

I'm trying to use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy all dependencies in a `/lib` folder next to the runnable jar. But it does not work:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- A jar that is opened as project in workspace, not installed into maven repo, and not a submodule. It should just be picked up and added as jar during package. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.domain</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-dependencies
>   (copy-dependencies) on project mydomain: Artifact has not been
>   packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact, copy should be executed
>   after packaging: see MDEP-187. -> [Help 1]

The error ocures when maven tries to copy the `commons` project that is open in the workspace. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem myself today, downloading the latest version of CTAKES (3.2) that integrates YTEX which would build on the command line but not in Eclipse. The error is a result of apparently a known issue with the plugin (https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-187).

I eventually fixed it (and I think this will fix your problem) by changing the phase from package to prepare-package.

package
to
prepare-package

Try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: Hit the same problem. Unfortunately changing the phase doesn't help.

Comment: My Eclipse still failing, but for command-line Maven it worked.